# Populating a form in template and updating new data

Tags: python, django

I tried this, but there is no update done in django.

```
def update_product(request):
    a= ProductForm(instance=Product.objects.get(product_id =2))#static id
    render_to_response('profiles/updateproduct.html',{'form': a},RequestContext(request))
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, instance=a)
        if form.is_valid():
            j=form.save(commit=False)
            j.save
            confirmation_message = "product information updated successfully!"
        return HttpResponse("hhhh")
    else:
        form = ProductForm( instance = a )
```

Answer (score 2):

You never actually call the model's `save` method since you are missing `()`. you must supply these in order to call the method.

```
j = form.save(commit=False)
j.save()
```

As a side note, since you are not doing anything to the model before saving it, you can simply replace these two lines with

```
j = form.save()
```

no real need here for the `commit=False` part.